# how to add JWT in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have added the authorization key as the given below

```
postrequest(callurl, input) {
const headers: any = new Headers;
headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8');
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer 
  '+localStorage.getItem("AuthTocken"));
return this._http.post(callurl, input, headers)
  .pipe(
    map((res: any) => {

      return res;
    }),
    retry(2),
    catchError(err => {
  })
 );
}
```

i didnt fount any error but the ***Authorisation*** is not found in the header

> angular **6**
>
> service used from **@angular/common/http**
>
> **URL working fine in postman**

i get the error as follows

> http.service.ts:84 Backend returned code 0, body was: [object ProgressEvent] body was: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":null,"ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
> (anonymous) @ http.service.ts:84
> push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error @ catchError.js:34

**Responce Headers**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ3yl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use `Bearer` instead of `Token`

```
headers.append('Authorisation', 'Bearer '+'localStorage.getItem("AuthTocken"));
```

header object is an option.
you must pass header as argument in below form

`this.http.post(url, data, {
  headers: headers
})`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have converted to Bearer, still it is not working

Comment: can you include your network response in your question??

Comment: it seems your browser is sending an OPTIONS request. its not a GET request. check your console. have you CORS error?

Answer (score 0):

It requires a slightly diffent setup.

EDIT: For brevity

```
this.httpClient.post(URLs, { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': localStorage.getItem("token") }); })
```

By the by, I realized you are spelling Authorization wrong. Thusly, it won't be recognized as a standard header.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am fetching the header by  **Authorisation** in my service

Comment: You shouldn't. At least, not without making it clear that you are using a custom header. Like X-Authorisation. And again, you should use for something so basic the official headers... 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization

Comment: Do I need to change to  Authorization it in the server?

Comment: i have coverted to Authorization and still it is not working

Comment: HOPEFULLY your server tracks a standard Authorization header. In the most likely event, you should simply rename your Authorisation to Authorization. If not... well, you might want to get that changed

Comment: What does the response from the backend say?

Comment: Well, looks more like the URL in question doesn't work. I mean, no headers are exposed, it's an entirely empty error block.

Comment: URL is working fine using _postman_ . when it comes to angular application, showing no jwt  is fount